# Displaying Chat Log Entries for a User in a Microsoft Teams Chat Screen

Tags: node.js, botframework, microsoft-teams

I'm developing a chatbot application on Node.js, utilizing [botbuilder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/botbuilder) library for a Microsoft Teams chatbot project. Occasionally, when my users input a question in the chat interface, they experience a delay of up to 30 seconds due to our back-end undertaking a complex task.

What I wish to implement is a way to keep the users engaged by displaying real-time updates regarding the back-end processing while they wait for their original query to be answered. Essentially, I want them to see messages that resemble log entries, similar to those visible in the attached screenshot from Teams

[image]

Initially, I assumed that `context.sendTraceActivity` would fulfill this task. However, it has been clarified in [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/botbuilder-core/turncontext?view=botbuilder-ts-latest#botbuilder-core-turncontext-sendtraceactivity) that this function is limited to working solely within a simulator environment.
What steps should I take to reach my goal?

Comment: Hello @Nostromo - If there is a delay beteen the user query and actual response, you can send the messages to users using await context.sendActivity("Please wait while processing your request."); or as per your business requirement.

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft hi, i don't prefer this approach but thank you anyway.

Comment: To keep your users engaged while your bot is processing a complex task, you can use Proactive Messaging. Proactive messages are those that are sent by a bot to start a conversation - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Please refer this code once - https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVn6n.png
In this example, the bot sends a proactive message to the user when it receives a message. The sendProactiveMessage function uses the createConversation method to start a new conversation with the user, and then uses the continueConversation method to send messages to the user. The setTimeout function is used to simulate a delay in processing the request.